# How to pass a dynamic model as 'T' to a C# generic function

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I have a generic function which is like below

```
private List<T> GetAll<T>()
{
    var listOfTModels = // gets the list of T from the database.

    return listOfTModels;
}
```

I need to pass the model ( T ) dynamically to this function based on a string which will be decided at runtime.

```
public void SomeFunction(string modelName)
{
     // Call the above Get method with modelName parameter as the 'T'

     var listOfModels = GetAll<something>(); //not sure what type this something should be "Type" or "string"

     // Further Logic on listOfModels
}
```

How could this be done?

Comment: On the DbContext there is the method `Set<T>()` which will return a DbSet of type T. And you can get `T` using Reflection

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use reflection to get the method like so:

```
typeof(ClassWithGetAll).GetMethod("GetAll",
                       BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

This will return a method info which you will then use to create a generic method via `MakeGenericMethod`.

The only way to get a type from a string name AFAIK is with [Type.GetType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.8) but you will need a [AssemblyQualifiedName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_AssemblyQualifiedName) for that, so passing in a short/simplified name like `string` or `int` or anything like that will more than likely return `null`.

If you figure out how to either get the qualified name or how to search for the type, the last thing would be to invoke the `MethodInfo` returned from the `MakeGenericMethod` call, here is a example of how the code could look:

```
public void SomeFunction(string modelName)
{
    // No idea what the class/struct in which the method "GetAll" 
   // is called, hence use this name
    var instance = new ClassWithGetAll();

    //Retrieves the info of "GetAll<T>"
    MethodInfo method = typeof(ClassWithGetAll).GetMethod("GetAll", 
                        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    //Commented out as you will need to figure out how to get the 
    // assembly qualified name of the input model name, unless 
    // it is qualified.
    //modelName = GetAssemblyQualifiedName(modelName);

    Type modelType = Type.GetType(modelName);

    //Creates a generic method: "GetAll<T>" => "GetAll<modelType>"
    method = method.MakeGenericMethod(modelType);

    //Invokes the newly created generic method in the specified 
    // instance with null parameters, which returns List<modelType>
    object list = method.Invoke(instance, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent.. Will try this approach and let you know if it helps in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think inheritance would be the right way to solve your problem.

```
public class TBase
{
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}
public class TChildOne : TBase
{

}
public class TChildTwo : TBase
{

}

public class GClass
{
    private List<T> GetAll<T>() where T : TBase
    {
        var listOfTModels = // gets the list of T from the database.
        return listOfTModels;
      }


    public void Main(string strType)
    {
        switch (strType)
        {
            case "TChildOne":
                {
                    var child = GetAll<TChildOne>();
                    break;
                }
            case "TChildTwo":
                {
                    var child = GetAll<TChildTwo>();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                throw new Exception("type not found");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But in my case I will have to write around 70 case statements each for 4 methods of such kind which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: How to implement inheritance if you have 200 tables in the database? Switch statement with 600 lines of code? this is not properly and dynamically passing object (model) name

Comment: The answer is based on the question, not consist of the context of using it. If you work with a database, I would recommend using a generic repository instead. Example 
https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/generic-repository-pattern-csharp-mvc/